# Custom template tag: where to actually put it in the template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

After completing the Django tutorial, I am trying to follow the instructions in the "Inclusion tags: section of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/ . I am not familiar with the syntax of template tags and I wasn't able to figure out reading the documents either.

polls_extra.py :

```py
from django import template
from django.template.loader import get_template
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('results.html')
def show_results(poll):
    choices = poll.choice_set.all()
    return {'choices': choices}
```

results.html :

```html
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{% load poll_extras %}
<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href= {% show_results poll %}>Vote again?</a>
```

Then when I submit a poll choice I get the error:

> AttributeError at /polls/1/results/
>
> 'str' object has no attribute 'choice_set'

How should it actually be included in the html?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with where you put the tag. You're passing "poll" as the argument, but you don't have anything called that in the template context; perhaps you meant "question"?

Comment: Although I also can't understand why you would use the result of that tag as the href in a link. That makes no sense at all.